# Expected declaration error when adding subview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Hi I got a "Expected declaration" error when I tried to add a subview to my UIView, here's the code:

```
@IBDesignable
class TimePickerView: UIView {

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/


    var borderWid = CGFloat(3.0)
    let square = UIView()
    square.frame = CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 50, height: 50) //line of error
    square.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    square.layer.borderWidth = borderWid
    self.view.addSubview(square)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare instance variable/properties (and assign default values) in your class outside of any function but you cannot include any other code.

All of the lines of code after the `let square = UIView()` need to go in a function, probably an initialiser.

Comment: thanks. I had to use two init() (`init(frame: CGRect)` and `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`) and put the setup in `init(_:frame)`. sorry it's kind of basic but I'm new to swift, and it's still somewhat confusing to me.